# Ruby: `gem_original_require': no such file to load -- rails (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I just deleted ruby 1.9.1 and installed 1.8.7, but my bash still points at 1.9.1 for when I look for rails.

```
emai@vpc-db:~$ rails --version
bash: /usr/local/bin/rails: /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

emai@vpc-db:~$ ruby --version
ruby 1.8.7 (2011-06-30 patchlevel 352) [x86_64-linux]
```

Can anyone help? How do I make bash look at 1.8.7?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to tell RubyGems to look elsewhere?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17624139/how-to-tell-rubygems-to-look-elsewhere)

Answer (score 2):

Your ruby is pretty old (and as of this week, officially deprecated). It's also really weird that your gems are installed in `/usr/local/bin`.

You might want to look into [rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv)

This will probably clean up your issue right away

---

**After** you have rbenv setup, I compile my rubies like this

```
# start in your home directory
cd $HOME    

# make a src folder for compiling ruby
mkdir -p .src && cd .src    

# download ruby
curl -O ftp://ftp.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/2.0/ruby-2.0.0-p247.tar.gz    

# extract compressed file
tar -xzf ruby-2.0.0-p247.tar.gz    

# cd to folder
cd ruby-2.0.0-p247    

# configure
./configure --prefix=$HOME/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247 --with-opt-dir=/path/to/openssl --enable-shared    

# make and install
make && make install    

# cleanup
rm -rf ruby-2.0.0-p247
```

Now let's use it!

```
# make rbenv aware of our new rubies
rbenv rehash

# set our new version as the default
rbenv global 2.0.0-p247

# let's check it out!
ruby --version
ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27 revision 41674) [x86_64-darwin12.3.0]
```

Now let's get that `rails` going

```
# install rails
gem install rails

# check the version
rails --version
Rails 4.0.0
```