# How to tell RubyGems to look elsewhere?

Tags: ruby

```
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:51:in `gem_original_require': no such file to load -- rails (LoadError)
from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:51:in `require'
from /usr/local/www/sl-exchange/lib/init.rb:4
from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:51:in `gem_original_require'
from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:51:in `require'
from /usr/local/www/sl-exchange/lib/exchange.rb:11
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/daemons-1.0.10/lib/daemons/application.rb:176:in `load'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/daemons-1.0.10/lib/daemons/application.rb:176:in `start_load'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/daemons-1.0.10/lib/daemons/application.rb:257:in `start'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/daemons-1.0.10/lib/daemons/controller.rb:69:in `run'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/daemons-1.0.10/lib/daemons.rb:139:in `run'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/daemons-1.0.10/lib/daemons/cmdline.rb:105:in `call'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/daemons-1.0.10/lib/daemons/cmdline.rb:105:in `catch_exceptions'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/daemons-1.0.10/lib/daemons.rb:138:in `run'
from ./data_exchange_preview:15
```

but when I do a `rails --version` in the terminal I get:

```
root@vpc-db:/usr/local/www/sl-exchange# rails --version
Rails 2.1.1
```

and `which rails` gives me `/usr/bin/rails`. I just deleted ruby 1.9.1 and installed 1.8.7 on my system so that might be why. It used to be located in /usr/local/bin

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/17624042/128421

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add a source:

```
gem sources -a URI
```

To see current environment

```
gem env
```

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to tell exactly what you've done.

You say you deleted Ruby 1.9.1 and installed 1.8.7 (which doesn't make a lot of sense since you went from a reasonably current version to one that has been unsupported for a while), and you don't say *how* you installed it.

Because you are on a Linux system, but didn't say which one, I'm assuming you didn't do it from source, which would have automatically included all the necessary Rubygems code. 1.8.7 did too, but when using a packaged install, often they separate out the necessary components, making it harder to get Ruby running.

As a result it's possible to delete the Ruby binary without removing the associated gems, then install another Ruby version, which leaves the gems associated with it orphaned or at least unassociated. That's what I think you did.

*My* recommendation is to remove all Ruby packages from your machine, then reinstall the current Ruby for your OS version.

Then, install [RVM](https://rvm.io/rvm/) or [rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv) to install Ruby in a sandbox in your home directory, and leave the system Ruby alone. RVM and rbenv make it very easy to install one or multiple Ruby versions. Each one will have its own, separate, set of gems.

Between RVM and rbenv, the simpler is rbenv. It doesn't have all the commands and features, nor is it as complicated as RVM, but either is better than installing from a package when you're developing and need to test against multiple Rubies. If you go with RVM, *READ THE ENTIRE INSTALLATION DIRECTIONS* so you understand your options, then install for a single-user.

On the systems I manage I only use packages to install a single Ruby on the test and production hosts. The developers on our shared development hosts and our desktops use RVM or rbenv for convenience and flexibility.